# Как перевести curl команду shell script в Python 3 с помощью pycurl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, shell, python-3.5

Использую python 3.5

Установил pycurl последней версии. Мне нужно перевести команду shell script:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer [API_key]" [graph_render_url] > [png_picture_path_full]
```

я попробовал сделать так:

```
with open(png_picture_path_full, 'wb') as f:
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(c.URL, graph_render_url)
    c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, f)
    c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ["Authorization: Bearer " + API_key])
    c.perform()
    c.close()
```

В итоге создается картинка, которая выдает ошибку. Внутри картинки закоддирована ошиюка http.

```
<!-- default "Cycle Detected" response (400) -->
```

Сurl ждя меня на данный момент темный лес. Как в shell так и в питоне. Я читаю документации но продвигась очень медленно. Мне очень поможет если я узна ответ на вопрос могу ли я вообще релизовать вышеуказанную строку в питоне? Если да, то в что мне следует учесть и как правильно построить команду?

Это не дубликат [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/648268/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83-curl-%D0%B2-requests-%D0%B2-python-3). в одном вопросе я спрашивал как перевести команду с помощью pycurl, в другой с помощью модуля requests. Хоть и они нужны для решения лжной и той же проблемы, ответы на эти вопросы предполагают разные ответы и использование разных модулей и команд.

Comment: А почему бы эту же команду в консоль не вбить? Или запустить процесс от curl и ему передать те параметры?

Comment: должен получиться автоматизированный процесс который будет выполняться каждый день. И функционала shell скрипта недостаточно для остальной части кода.

Comment: Я не говорю про консоль, я говорю про сам язык. Из самого скрипта можно запустить команду в консоли или создать процесс curl. Посмотрите в сторону `os.system` и модуль `subprocess`

Comment: Я, к соэалению, это уже делал. Субпроцессы у меня тоже не пошли... http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/646175/%D0%95%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-curl-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python

Comment: потому что надо так shell_command = ["curl", "-H ", ... ]

Comment: Я понадеялся на секунду, но ваш вариант, к сожалению тоже не работает.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно перевести команду curl в requests в python 3?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/648268/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%83-curl-%d0%b2-requests-%d0%b2-python-3)

Comment: Это не дуюликат, в одном вопросе я спрашивал как перевести крманду с помощью pycurl, в другой с помощью модуля requests. Хоть и они нужны для одного решения, ответы на эти вопросы будут совершенно разные.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нашел решeние с помощью другого модуля "requests".

[Как правильно перевести команду curl в requests в python 3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/648268/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83-curl-%D0%B2-requests-%D0%B2-python-3)

```
import requests
import shutil

headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJrIjoiV29Gd2ZlbkQyS'}
r = requests.get(graph_render_url, headers=headers, stream=True)
with open([png_picture_path_full], 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, out_file)
    del r
```