# Как сохранить картинку используя requests на основе curl команды

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, shell, requests

Я вызывал следующую команду в shell скрипте и хочу перевести ее в питон.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJrIjoiV29Gd2ZlbkQyS" [http://localhost:8080/graph_render_url] > picture.png
```

Что я написал.

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJrIjoiV29Gd2ZlbkQyS'}
r = requests.get("http://localhost:8080/graph_render_url", headers=headers)
```

Как перевести этот request в картинку picture.png?

Comment: Точнее заголовок: как сохранить картинку используя requests: [How to download image using requests](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13137817/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос. спасибо за внимание.

```
import requests
import shutil

headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJrIjoiV29Gd2ZlbkQyS'}
r = requests.get(graph_render_url, headers=headers, stream=True)
with open("picture.png", 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, out_file)
    del r
```

Comment: 1- Не хватает `r.raw.decode_content=True`  как явно показано в [ответе по ссылке, которую я выше привёл](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13137873/4279). 2- `del r` ни к чему.

Comment: Можете объяснить для чего нужна эта команда? код работает и без неё.

Comment: Почитайте зачем нужны: Content-Encoding, Accept-Encoding http заголовки.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так:

> > url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
> >
> > > files = {'file': open('report.xls', 'rb')}
> > >
> > > r = requests.post(url, files=files)
> > >       r.text
> > >       {
> > >         ...
> > >         "files": {
> > >           "file": ""
> > >         },
> > >         ...
> > >       }

Вот ссылка на документацию Requests, где это описано: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

Comment: спасибо, я нашел уже доугойе решение.